# I need to insert data into a table which consists of 1 primary (AUTO_INCREMENT ) and 3 foreign keys

Tags: mysql

Table containing 1 primary key and 3 foreign keys; Order_ID 'Customer_ID','Item_ID', 'DateTime_ID'

Now, the DateTime table is updated simultaneously as the row containing the previous "1 primary and 3 foreign keys" is inserted.

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO datetime (DateTime_ID, OrderDate, OrderTime) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_DATE (), CURRENT_TIME() )" ;
```

But I am struggling to work out an INSERT INTO query.

This is what I have so far:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO myorder VALUES ('NULL', menu_item WHERE item_id='$item', customer WHERE Customer_ID='$id' '$sql1')";
```

`'$sql1'` being a guess to insert the first query simultaneously.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not really clear but you may try something like this:

```
DECLARE p_datetime_id INTEGER;
DECLARE p_customer_id INTEGER;
DECLARE p_item_id     INTEGER;

-- Initialize customer and item
SET p_customer_id = ...;
SET p_item_id = ...;

-- Create datetime element
INSERT INTO datetime (OrderDate, OrderTime)
  VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME());
SET p_datetime_id = IDENTITY();

-- Create order element
INSERT INTO myorder (Customer_ID, Item_ID, DateTime_ID)
  VALUES (p_customer_id, p_item_id, p_datetime_id);
```